# Azure scaling of roles and pricing

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

I have been digging without being able to wrap my head around this. It seems like once a role is deployed, you are charged for it in full, whether or not you scale it up or down?

Why would anyone scale down with this? I don't see the incentive to not just leave the role with all possible instances used to max?

I can see why an availability set, with several roles, might want to distribute the cores between them depending on load. But is that all it's for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pay the price of one instance of choosen size (A0 to D14) multiplied per the number of instance that are running.

Try with the [Azure Princing Calculator](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=cloud), the number of instance increases charges.

When you try to use [Autoscaling](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-scale/) it clearly states :

> Autoscale is saving you XX% off your current bill